# Mysql not inserting binary data properly

Tags: php, mysql, bit

I am working on data compression and for some reason i need only 8 bits.
I am converting number by decbin() and then inserting it in the mysql, the mysql column data type BIT width is 8 bit. I used `mysql_query("INSERT INTO n (reading) VALUES (b'".$value."')")` and tried this one too`mysql_query("INSERT INTO n (reading) VALUES (".$value.")")`. Before inserting the value is fine but after insertion its not the same value, it changes the value for example before insertion it echo the value `116` then I echo its binary value `1110100` and it insert the value in mysql column is `00110000`.

```
function delta($reading){
    global $flag;
    $delta = $flag - $reading;
    saveDelta(decbin($delta));       
}
```

here is the other function where it saves the value

```
function saveDelta($dif) {
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO n (reading) VALUES (".$dif.")");    
}
```

Comment: Could you show some more code? For example, how you (re)read data from the DB. For what I see, you have no mean to retrieve the values in the order they where entered at first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `"INSERT INTO n (reading) VALUES (b'".$value."')"` should work provided that `$value` is properly encoded as a string of `'0'` and `'1'`.

**EDIT:** I noticed you didn't provide any "sequence number" while inserting your data. But, please remember that without using a proper `ORDER BY` clause, you cannot retrieve your *bytes* the order they where entered at first. Maybe you think you read "116" but MySQL return an other row from the table?

---

Here are some usage examples, First using the [`BIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-type.html) type:

```
CREATE TABLE b (value BIT(8));
INSERT INTO b VALUES (0),(1), (255);
INSERT INTO b VALUES (b'00000000'),(b'00000001'), (b'11111111');
```

Please note  that when retrieving `BIT` columns you will obtain *signed* result (i.e.: storing *255* will read *-1*).

You could retrieve your data either as *signed* 10-base integers or binary form (with optional padding):

```
SELECT value FROM b;
SELECT BIN(value) FROM b;
SELECT LPAD(BIN(value), 8, '0') FROM b;
```

---

As of myself, I would prefer the [`TINYINT UNSIGNED`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html). This is an 8 bit type which support the same syntax for values (either *<10-base digit>* or *b'xxxxxxxx'*) -- but will accept the `UNSIGNED` specifier:

```
CREATE TABLE t (value TINYINT UNSIGNED);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (0),(1),(255);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (b'00000000'),(b'00000001'), (b'11111111');
```

You could retrieve your data either as *unsigned* 10-base integers or binary form (with optional padding):

```
SELECT value FROM t;
SELECT BIN(value) FROM t;
SELECT LPAD(BIN(value), 8, '0') FROM t;
```

---

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ff44/6 to experiment with both of them.

Comment: i made the 

    `table CREATE TABLE b (value BIT(8));`
inserted values like that 

    `INSERT INTO b VALUES (b'00000000');`
and like 

    `INSERT INTO b VALUES (00000000);`
and when i try to <br/>
    `SELECT LPAD(BIN(reading)) FROM n;`
it gives blank result and when i try 
    `SELECT BIN(reading) FROM n;` or `SELECT reading FROM n;`
it gives me result `id #7, id #8, id #9 .....`

Comment: do you know why its doing this ?